# For loops with date ranges in R

Tags: r, for-loop, date-range

Hi I am trying to figure out how to substitute assigned values to a date range, for running a for loop. The full code is much longer than this, but basically I am having trouble properly substituting in the i value into the code blocks. Any tips would be helpful!

Generally what I am looking for:

```
for (i in 1994:2019) {

df <- data.frame(date=seq(from=as.Date(i-04-1"),to=as.Date(i-10-1"),by="month"))

}
```

Comment: see 'paste' or 'paste0'

Comment: I have been trying but I think how I am formatting it is wrong, would you be able to write an example of how you would integrate paste in this instance, with the dates?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `paste0` function

```r
for (i in 1994:2019) {
  df <- data.frame(date=seq(from=as.Date(paste0(i, "-04-1")),to=as.Date(paste0(i,"-10-1")),by="month"))
}
```